# Worklight Facebook platform selection?

Tags: facebook, ibm-mobilefirst

For Facbook integration in Worklight which platform should we select **Android** or **Website**
,[image: Select Platform]

right now i am developing for android environment but later i will be doing for iphone and windows as well 
Also were do i place the Facebook integration code in index.html(main) or in android project which is separately created ? 
 i am confused do reply

Comment: You will be able to add other platforms later. Just click on the one you want to add now

Comment: You mean now i should select Android
and where do i place the code in Worklight project itself ?

Comment: If you creating an Android app yes. Why would you select something else?

Comment: "Wizkid", are you familiar with worklight? If not you should not answer with such conviction.

Comment: Swati, if you are developing a hybrid worklight app then you should use facebook's JavaScript SDK and place it in common\js so that it will be available for any environment you will add to your worklight project.

Comment: If you will choose to use the native SDK for each platform then you will need to add it to the native folder of each environment using the appropriate SDK for each one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are developing a Worklight-based **Hybrid application**, so in this case you should actually opt for the Facebook [**JavaScript** SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript).

You can add it to your common\js folder and reference it in the common\index.html (just follow the instructions Facebook probably provides). This way you could easily 'extend' it to whichever additional environments you will add in Worklight Studio in your project setup.

Of course, you can also choose to use Facebook's native SDKs for each environment in your Hybrid application. In this case, you'll need to add the SDK in the iphone-ipad-or-android\native folder and follow Facebook's integration instructions (note that for iPhone the actual integration will be done in Xcode, not Eclipse).

If you choose to create a **native application** and bundle it with the Worklight SDK, then you should opt for the Facebook SDK dedicated to the specific OS. Here, you will add the SDK, again, by following Facebook's instructions.